# why cssclass not applied when i click button in repeater c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi everyone i try all ways to solve this problem and no solution

I have dropdownlist inside repeater and button for remove this dropdownlist also i have add button outside repeter for adding dropdownlist the problem is whin i click button i loss all cssclass outside of repeater i have checkbox with cssclass and its work normally if i don't click button

[image]
 [image]

this is my code

```
   <div id="content">

    <table id="tableDescription" style="width:65%">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" OnDataBinding="Repeater1_DataBinding" OnPreRender="Repeater1_PreRender" >
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>

      <td valign="middle" style="width:100%">
            <table >
            <tr>
            <td  style="width:100%">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="txtDescription"   runat="server"  CssClass="form-control input-lg m-bot15" Height="45px" Width="87%">     <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Select Degree" />
   </asp:DropDownList> 
            </td>
            <td style="width:100%;" valign="left">
                <asp:Button   ID="btnRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ToolTip="Remove this description"   Height="45px" /> 
            </td>
            </tr>
                <tr style="height:20PX;">
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <tr>
    <td align="right"> 
          <asp:Button  ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Add Languge"     OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                <td class="auto-style57">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td class="auto-style56">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table> 

 </div>
                                      </div>
                                      </div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">   
                                    <div class="content-body">    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                                    <table cellspacing="0" class="auto-style7">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblfood" runat="server" Text="Food &amp; drink"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRN" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="skin-flat-green"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblreturantneer" runat="server" Text="Restaurants near"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRD" runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblGROCERY_DELIVERIES" runat="server" Text="Resturant Deliveries"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBBQ" runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblBBQ_FACILITIES" runat="server" Text="BBQ Area"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDM" runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblVENDING_MACHINE_DRINKS" runat="server" Text="Drinks Machine"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkMS" runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblVENDING_MACHINE_SNACKS" runat="server" Text="Snack Machine"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBuffet" runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;</td>
                                            <td style="margin-left: 40px">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblBUFFET_STYLE_RESTAURANT" runat="server" Text="BUFFET"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSnack" runat="server" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblSNACK_BAR" runat="server" Text="Snack"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div></div>
                               </td>
                        </tr>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chkfee.InputAttributes["class"] = "iswitch iswitch-md iswitch-primary";
    chkactiv.InputAttributes["class"] = "iswitch iswitch-md iswitch-primary";
    chkownercontact.InputAttributes["class"] = "iswitch iswitch-md iswitch-primary";
    myTable.Columns.Add("degreeCode");
    DateTable.Columns.Add("DateFrom");
    DateTable.Columns.Add("DateTo");
    DateTable.Columns.Add("DatePrice");


    { 

    #region food
    chkRN.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkBBQ.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkSnack.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkMS.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkRD.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkDM.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkBuffet.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    #endregion 

    #region activities
    chkTeenis.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkBilliards.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkTableTeenis.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkSquash.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkBowling.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkMG.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    ChkWS.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkGolf.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkwindsurfing.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkDiving.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkFishing.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkHR.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkcycling.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkWD.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkSelling.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkVB.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkFB.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkGDB.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    #endregion

    #region Pool
    chkINpool.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkPS.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkIPAY.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkOutPool.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkOutPAY.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkBA.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkBechfront.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkSpa.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkSuna.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkTB.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkHT.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkFC.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chksolarium.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkMassage.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkOPS.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkKP.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    #endregion

    #region Misc
    chkadult.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkDSA.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkheating.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkGR.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkPG.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkCS.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkhearth.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chksingles.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkPets.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkAllNS.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkAirCond.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkGrean.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkKidesarea.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkMN.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkBShar.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkFO.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkSinglFamily.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chktree.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";


    #endregion

    #region paymethod
    chkvisa.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkvisa.CssClass  = "skin-flat-green";
    chkmastercard.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chksadad.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    chkpayatplace.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-flat-green";
    #endregion
    BindImages();

    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        txtDateFromPrice.CssClass = "form-control datepicker col-md-4";
        DataTable ImgTable = new DataTable();

        DataRow dr;
        ImgTable.Columns.Add("PROPERTY_IMAG_ID");
        ImgTable.Columns.Add("PROPERTY_IMAG");
        ImgTable.Columns.Add("PROPERTY_PROPERTY_IMAG_PROP_ID");
        ImgTable.Columns.Add("PROPERTY_IMAG_SIZE");
        ImgTable.Columns.Add("PROPERTY_IMAG_TYPE");
        dr = ImgTable.NewRow();
        ImgTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        ViewState["ImgTablestate"] = ImgTable;
        myTable = (DataTable)ViewState["myTablestate"];

        DLCountry.DataSource = GH.GetCountries();
        DLCountry.DataTextField = "EnglishName";
        DLCountry.DataValueField = "id";
        DLCountry.DataBind();

        DLGroup.DataSource = OH.GetOwnerGroup();
        DLGroup.DataTextField = "OWNER_GROUPE_TYPE";
        DLGroup.DataValueField = "OWNER_GROUPE_ID";
        DLGroup.DataBind();

        dt = prop.GetNextIDProperty();
        dtfile = IH.GetNextIDIMAGES();
        HIDFOLDERID.Value = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        HiddenFILEID.Value = HiddenFILEID.Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(HIDFOLDERID.Value + "1406") + 1);
        BindImages();
        Bind();
         BindRepetDate();
        DLLanguge.DataSource = GH.GetCountries();
        DLLanguge.DataTextField = "EnglishName";
        DLLanguge.DataValueField = "id";
        DLLanguge.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
        DLLanguge.DataBind();

    }
}

protected void NewRegistrationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Bind()
{


    Repeater1.DataSource = myTable;
    Repeater1.DataBind();

}
////////
  [WebMethod]
public void BindImages()
{
   // GridImag.DataSource = ImgTable;
    GridImag.DataBind();
    GridImag.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
public static bool DeleteFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {

        if (File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath)))
        {

            File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath));

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    catch
    {

        return false;

    }

}



protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    long img_id=rand.Next();
    dt = prop.GetNextIDProperty();

    HIDFOLDERID.Value = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    HiddenFILEID.Value = Convert.ToString(img_id);
   // ImgTable = (DataTable)ViewState["ImgTable"];

     string type,size;
    if (txtImage.UploadedFiles.Count > 0)
    {
        if (IH.CheckAndCreateFolder(HIDFOLDERID.Value) == true)
        {
            foreach (var file in from UploadedFile file in txtImage.UploadedFiles select file)
            {

               type = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
               var filePath = string.Format("/properties_images/" + HIDFOLDERID.Value + "/{0}"+type, HiddenFILEID.Value);
               type = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower();
                string fileSize = file.ContentLength.ToString();
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
                if (ViewState["ImgTablestate"] != null)
                {
                    //get datatable from view state   
                    DataTable ImgTable1 = (DataTable)ViewState["ImgTablestate"];
                    DataRow ImgTablerow = ImgTable1.NewRow();

                    if (ImgTable1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                        for (int i = 1; i <= ImgTable1.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {

                            //add each row into data table  
                            ImgTablerow["PROPERTY_IMAG_ID"] = HiddenFILEID.Value;
                            ImgTablerow["PROPERTY_IMAG"] = filePath;
                            ImgTablerow["PROPERTY_PROPERTY_IMAG_PROP_ID"] = HIDFOLDERID.Value;
                            ImgTablerow["PROPERTY_IMAG_SIZE"] = fileSize;
                            ImgTablerow["PROPERTY_IMAG_TYPE"] = type;


                        }
                        //Remove initial blank row  
                        if (ImgTable1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                        {
                            ImgTable1.Rows[0].Delete();
                            ImgTable1.AcceptChanges();

                        }

                        //add created Rows into dataTable  
                        ImgTable1.Rows.Add(ImgTablerow);
                        //Save Data table into view state after creating each row  
                        ViewState["ImgTablestate"] = ImgTable1;
                        //Bind Gridview with latest Row  
                        GridImag.DataSource = ImgTable1;
                        GridImag.DataBind();
                        GridImag.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var file in from UploadedFile file in txtImage.UploadedFiles select file)
            {

                type = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
                var filePath = string.Format("/properties_images/" + HIDFOLDERID.Value + "/{0}" + type, HiddenFILEID.Value);
                string fileSize = file.ContentLength.ToString();
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
                //IH.insertImages(Convert.ToInt64(HIDFOLDERID.Value), filePath, fileSize, type);
                if (ViewState["ImgTablestate"] != null)
                {
                    //get datatable from view state   
                    DataTable ImgTable1 = (DataTable)ViewState["ImgTablestate"];
                    DataRow ImgTablerow = ImgTable1.NewRow();

                    if (ImgTable1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {

                        for (int i = 1; i <= ImgTable1.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {

                            //add each row into data table  
                            ImgTablerow["PROPERTY_IMAG_ID"] = HiddenFILEID.Value;
                            ImgTablerow["PROPERTY_IMAG"] = filePath;
                            ImgTablerow["PROPERTY_PROPERTY_IMAG_PROP_ID"] = HIDFOLDERID.Value;
                            ImgTablerow["PROPERTY_IMAG_SIZE"] = fileSize;
                            ImgTablerow["PROPERTY_IMAG_TYPE"] = type;


                        }
                        //Remove initial blank row  
                        if (ImgTable1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                        {
                            ImgTable1.Rows[0].Delete();
                            ImgTable1.AcceptChanges();

                        }

                        //add created Rows into dataTable  
                        ImgTable1.Rows.Add(ImgTablerow);
                        //Save Data table into view state after creating each row  
                        ViewState["ImgTablestate"] = ImgTable1;
                        //Bind Gridview with latest Row  
                        GridImag.DataSource = ImgTable1;
                        GridImag.DataBind();
                        GridImag.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    }
                }
             }  


            }
        }

    }

protected void GridImag_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridImag.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindImages();
}
protected void GridImag_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (GridImag.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    else
    {
        GridImag.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        GridImag.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
}
protected void GridImag_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void DeleteImagesClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = HDurl.Value.ToString();

    string check = WHois.Value.ToString();

    if (check == "I")
    {
        long imgid = Convert.ToInt64(hiddenF.Value);
        //IH.DeleteImages(imgid);
        DeleteFile(filePath);
        DataTable ImgTable1 = (DataTable)ViewState["ImgTablestate"];
        for (int i = 0; i < ImgTable1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ImgTable1.Rows[i]["PROPERTY_IMAG_ID"].ToString() == hiddenF.Value)
         {
             ImgTable1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
         }
        }
        GridImag.DataSource = ImgTable1;
        GridImag.DataBind();
        GridImag.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }
}
protected void PopulateDataTable()
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        DropDownList txtDescription = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("txtDescription");
        DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();
        row["degreeCode"] = txtDescription.SelectedValue.ToString();
        myTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    PopulateDataTable();
    myTable.Rows[e.Item.ItemIndex].Delete();
    Bind();
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PopulateDataTable();
    myTable.Rows.Add(myTable.NewRow());
    ViewState["myTablestate"] = myTable;
    Bind();
    DataTable ImgTable1 = (DataTable)ViewState["ImgTablestate"];
    GridImag.DataSource = ImgTable1;
    GridImag.DataBind();
    GridImag.SelectedIndex = -1; 
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {

        var txtDescription = e.Item.FindControl("txtDescription") as DropDownList;
        string degreeCode = Convert.ToString(((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["degreeCode"]);
        if (txtDescription != null)
        {
            txtDescription.DataSource = GH.GetCountries();
            txtDescription.DataTextField = "EnglishName";
            txtDescription.DataValueField = "id";
            txtDescription.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
            txtDescription.DataBind(); 
            if (txtDescription.Items.FindByValue(degreeCode) != null)
                txtDescription.SelectedValue = degreeCode;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    DataTable ImgTable1 = (DataTable)ViewState["ImgTablestate"];
    GridImag.DataSource = ImgTable1;
    GridImag.DataBind();
    GridImag.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
protected void BindRepetDate()
{
    RepeaterDate.DataSource = DateTable;
    RepeaterDate.DataBind();

}

protected void PopulateDataTableDateRepet()
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepeaterDate.Items)
    {

        TextBox txtDateFromPriceRepet = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtDateFromPriceRepet");
        TextBox txtDateToPriceRepet = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtDateToPriceRepet");
        TextBox txtPriceSpicific = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtPriceSpicific");
        DataRow row = DateTable.NewRow();
        row["DateFrom"] = txtDateFromPriceRepet.Text;
        row["DateTo"] = txtDateToPriceRepet.Text;
        row["DatePrice"] = txtPriceSpicific.Text;
        DateTable.Rows.Add(row);

    }
}

protected void RepeaterDate_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    PopulateDataTableDateRepet();
    DateTable.Rows[e.Item.ItemIndex].Delete();
    BindRepetDate();
    DataTable ImgTable1 = (DataTable)ViewState["ImgTablestate"];
    GridImag.DataSource = ImgTable1;
    GridImag.DataBind();
    GridImag.SelectedIndex = -1;
}

protected void btnAddDateRepet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PopulateDataTableDateRepet();
    DateTable.Rows.Add(DateTable.NewRow());
    BindRepetDate();
    DataTable ImgTable1 = (DataTable)ViewState["ImgTablestate"];
    GridImag.DataSource = ImgTable1;
    GridImag.DataBind();
    GridImag.SelectedIndex = -1;

}
```

Comment: Your question is not full. When you click on which button? which elements lose styling?

Comment: when i click button inside the repeater remove button or outside repeater Add button the style of checkbox which is outside of repeter the cssclass not applied look at the pictures

Comment: Both pictures are the same. How mush I compare that???

Comment: it's not the same look at checkbox in first picture the checkbox cssclass is applied but after click add the checkbox in the second picture it is turned to default style